# How to get rid of the coolant fan noise in NVR

Tags: audio, cooling, fanless, nvr

Hi I'm using the following NVR

https://www.dahuasecurity.com/products/All-Products/Network-Recorders/Lite-Series/NVR4/L-Series/1HDD/NVR4108HS-4KS2/L

But the fan is really noisy enough to disturb the sleep.

Please checkout the [AV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13W2MsRnve7HH_5ln23VZdWsBpJIzNYwk/view?usp=sharing)

What I did so far.

I opened the NVR and tried adjusting the cooling fan but the noise started coming again.

I can't remove the fan as this would reduce the lifespan of circuits.

Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Answer (score -1):

Makes sure that the blades of the fan are clean and so is the grill.

If thats not enough then replace the fan.  You will need the model number, or the dimensions and rating which is normally on the centre hub.

Comment: Please try to resist the temptation to answer off-topic questions - it gives people the [unfortunately now correct] impression they can ask anything & get an answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin - What's the right stack overflow group to ask this ?

Comment: Perhaps https://superuser.com/